# Приложение qt не работает русский язык

Tags: c++, windows, qt, кодировка, кириллица

пишу в qt creator, создал консольное приложение без qt, но русские буквы выводятся крокозябрами:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом `setlocale` не помогает, и крокозябры меняются на эти:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

судя по всему это конфликт utf-8 и сp1251, но в консоли у меня по умолчанию 866dos и при изменении кодировки исходников ошибка сохраняется, при использовании chcp 65001 первая буква, если она русская заменяется всегда на квадратики, и мне не нравится лишняя надпись сверху:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] как сделать нормальное отображение русских букв? 
P.S qt 5.11.0, win7 32bit, компилятор minGW который по умолчанию с qt идет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextCodec>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString string = "Привет, Мир!";

    // variant1
    std::cout << QTextCodec::codecForName("CP866")->fromUnicode(string).data() << std::endl;

    // variant2
    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("CP866"));
    qDebug() << string;

    return a.exec();
}
```